# how to export a function and the variable returned by the function es6 typescript sequelize

Tags: typescript, module, sequelize.js, export

I'm new to typescript (and es6) and sequelize,*

I would like to be able to get to export a function that can return also an variable exported.

Here is my server.ts

```
import express from "express";
import { routing } from "./routes/routes";
import connectToDatabase from "./databases/config";
import 'dotenv/config'

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

routing(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

const sequelize = connectToDatabase();
```

here is my config.ts that contain the function to connect to my database and that should also return me my "sequelize" instance to be used in my models.

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

export const sequelize = async function connectToDatabase()
{
    if(!process.env.DB_URI)
    {
        throw new Error("DB_URI is not defined");
    }
    
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_URI);
    
    try
    {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log("Connection to database has been established successfully.");
        return sequelize
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
    }
    finally
    {
        sequelize.close();
    }
}
```

but now in my user model I would like to get the "sequelize" I instancied in config.ts to do something like this :

```
import { sequelize } from "../config";
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
},
{
    sequelize,
    modelName: "User"
});
```

Comment: are you seeing an error with the above code?

Comment: yes it say that connectToDatabase() need an default export since i export only the variable, how can I call only one time connectToDatabase() but get sequelize everywhere I want ?